# How to read a .sav SPSS file in in R?

Tags: r, character-encoding, statistics, spss, cp1252

I've tried `read.spps()`, but I get an encoding error:

```
library(foreign)
read.spss('persona.sav')
#>re-encoding from CP1252
```

> Error in iconv(names(rval), cp, "") :
> unsupported conversion from 'CP1252' to ''
> In addition: Warning message:
> In read.spss("persona.sav") :
> persona.sav: Unrecognized record type 7, subtype 18 encountered in system file

Comment: I prefer `spss.system.file` from package `memisc`. Use as `x <- as.data.frame(as.data.set(spss.system.file(...)))`.

Comment: Sadly, I can't use `memisc` (for now, not for technical reasons). Thanks for the tip, I'll push to solve that blocker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try re-encoding it as a utf-8 file:

```
 library(foreign)
 read.spss('persona.sav', reencode='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `'to.data.frame = TRUE'` into  `read.spss()`

For instance:

```
df <- read.spss("data.sav", to.data.frame = TRUE)
```